# jndi.properties in JBoss and GlassFish deployment

Tags: jboss, glassfish, jndi, portability

Currently an EJB / Web Application project uses a JBoss-specific JNDI configuration file, placed either in the conf directory or in the Jar file (both works fine).

How can I make this project portable between JBoss (4.2.3 or 5) and GlassFish 3? Is there a recommended way to set different JNDI configuration parameters depending on the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their [EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB), Glassfish developers have put a `jndi.properties` file within `appserv-rt.jar`. The JNDI machinery in Java SE automatically detects this file when used in conjunction with no-arg `InitialContext()` and bootstraps the correct naming provider.

My understanding is that this should work in Glassfish also. Did you try do deploy your application without the `jndi.properties` file specific to JBoss (and to place it into the conf directory when deploying on JBoss)?